# Inserir dados no banco através de um dataGridview em C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um formulário em C#:

[image: Formulário]

Neste formulário há um `textbox` onde digito o dia da semana e um `datagrid` onde digito as horas.

Eu coloquei uma coluna chamada horário, com `DataGridViewCellStyle { Format=t }` manual. Mas a mascara `__:__` não está aparecendo em tempo de execução. Estou usando o seguinte loop para salvar.

```
void INSERIRHORARIO()
{
    //Instância da conexão onde passo a
    //ConnectionString
    var conn = new MySqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Server=10.1.1.50;database=sistema_escola;uid=alfa;pwd=;");
    // //sql que será executado na tabela cliente
    var sql = "INSERT INTO dia_hora (dia, horario, qtdVagas) " +
              "VALUES (@dia, @horario, @qtdVagas)";
    //instância do comando onde passo
    //o sql e a conexão como parâmetro
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
    //abro a conexão
    strSelect = "SELECT SUM(qtdVagas) AS Vagas FROM laboratorio";
    DataTable tabela;
    tabela = conexao.ExecultarSelect(strSelect);
    conn.Open();

    //percorro o DataGridView
    for (int i = 0; i < dGVHorario.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        //limpo os parâmetros
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        //crio os parâmetro do comando
        //e passo as linhas do dgvClientes para eles
        //onde a célula indica a coluna do dgv
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dia", txtDiadaSemana.Text);
        //dGVHorario.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@horario", dGVHorario.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qtdVagas", tabela.Rows[0]["Vagas"].ToString());

        //executo o comando
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    //Fecho conexão
    conn.Close();
```

Mas, estou trabalhando com orientação objeto, então eu já tenho uma classe para conexão, e um classe para cadastrar os horários. Há como fazer loop para pegar a conexão de minha classe e enviar os dados para a classe de horário?

**Classe dia_hora**

```
public class dia_hora : ModeloCrud { 
    private string dia; 
    private string horario; 
    private int qtdVagas; 
    public string Dia 
    { 
        get { return dia; } 
        set { dia = value; } 
    } 
    public string Horario 
    { 
        get { return horario; } 
        set { horario = value; } 
    }       
    public int QtdVagas 
    { 
        get { return qtdVagas; } 
        set { qtdVagas = value; } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Se você colocar a classe conexão e a classe para cadastrar horário eu consigo te ajudar, mas, o código acima ta uma salada de fruta, porque abre com a `conn` ai no meio do código tem um `conexao`, deve ta errado alguma coisa, bom como eu disse disponibilize as classes!

Comment: Clesse do horário
public class dia_hora : ModeloCrud
    {
        private string dia;
        private string horario;
        private int qtdVagas;

        public string Dia
        {
            get { return dia; }
            set { dia = value; }
        }
        public string Horario
        {
            get { return horario; }
            set { horario = value; }
        }
        public int QtdVagas
        {
            get { return qtdVagas; }
            set { qtdVagas = value; }
        }

Comment: Coloque editando a sua questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/28827/edit

Comment: A classe conexão não cabe aqui. Mas ela faz a conexão com o banco. kkkk

Comment: Fabricio dá sim olha lá eu editei e coloque a classe dia_hora.

Comment: Maria Bem, a classe de dia_horario a classe que faz a persistência das informações no banco. Como eu coloquei acima. Eu tenho um insert automático ele pega os atributo e valores automático das classes por isso tenho que passar os dados para lá. Do tipo que o código está la em cima ele está gravando no banco, mas jó pensou se eu tiver trocar o caminho do servidor, onde tiver o código vou ter sair trocando. por isso OO.

Comment: Só uma dica amigo Fabricio, quando eu vi isso aqui `dia_hora : ModeloCrud` já me deu subsidios para dizer que seu modelo pode estar funcional, mas, fora do padrão e são poucas informações para qualquer um responder, desculpe gosto do estimulo, mas, tive que fazer uma critica construtiva... Desculpe novamente!

Comment: tranquilo, preciso mesmo como fazer essa informações passarem pela classe sem fazer um conexão direta. Como está ai emcima

Comment: Ala maria novamente. Valeu a dica vou deixa minha solução em baico valeu mesmo

Answer (score 1):

```
strSelect = "SELECT SUM(qtdVagas) AS Vagas FROM laboratorio";
DataTable tabela;
tabela = conexao.ExecutarSelect(strSelect);
```

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvhorario.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
     diahora.Dia = txtDiadaSemana.Text;
     diahora.Horario = Convert.ToString(dgvhorario.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
     diahora.QtdVagas =Convert.ToInt32(tabela.Rows[0]["Vagas"].ToString());
     diahora.SALVAR();
}
```